# Dropdown text with customs?

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, android-xml, dropdown

In Android, is there any functionality that allows people to either choose a word/phrase from a dropdown, or enter their own?

In other words the dropdown texts are really more like common examples for convenience, but if the user wants to do something else, they can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about `AutoCompleteTextView`. You can use it in this way :

Add the following code to your .xml file

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/auto_text"
    android:hint="Enter something here..."/>
```

You can add other attributes to this according to your layout type. And add this code in your Activity or .java file

```
string[] drop_down = {"item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","...and so on"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AutoCompleteTextView text1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto_text);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.drop_down, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    text1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Note that**, you will have to import these two packages to use the following:

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
```

Tell me if you were asking for this or not ?